# Ruby on Railsでサーバー起動後と停止前に処理を書く場合のベストプラクティスを教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby初心者です。

いくつかのWebアプリケーションフレームワークでは、サーバー起動後（boot時）や停止前（Ctrl+Cを押された場合など）にユーザーのカスタム処理を書くフックポイントが用意されていると思いますが、
Ruby on Railsで同様のことがしたい場合のベストプラクティスはありますでしょうか？
以下のサイトなどを見るとできそうではありますが、あまり正式な方法ではないように思います。
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

複数サーバーでのスケールアウトが主流の世の中で、サーバーインスタンスの起動、停止にフックして処理すること自体、あまり必要性がないのかもしれませんが、参考までに質問です。

Comment: 基本それが正式な方法です。具体的に、どういった処理を挟みたいのでしょうか。その処理の内容によって「このファイルが適切だ」とか「それはrailsの範疇外だ」といった回答がつくかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。なるほど、そうなんですね。例えば、起動後に、あるコントローラの処理を呼びたい（定期監視を開始するAPIを起動後に自分で呼ぶなど）、停止前にDB内のステータス管理しているテーブルを更新したり、削除したい、サーバー内の実行中のJOBがないかチェックしたい、などです。いずれも、サーバーがシングルインスタンスの設計に向いているのと、JOB管理などをちゃんとやるなら、WEBサーバとは別のフレームワークでちゃんとやるべきでしょうが、ちょっとしたシングルインスタンスのアプリで上記のフックがあると便利な時はあります。
Play frameworkなどでは、Globalってオブジェクトをかけば、そこでいろんなWEBサーバーのイベントフックができるので、便利でした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントより

起動通知だけなら config/initializers配下でも良いと思いますが。
残念ながらconfig/finalizersのようなものがありません。

ベストプラクティスというのは、なかなか難しいものですが。
私の場合は、よくこういうrakeタスクを書きます。

```
[lib/tasks/server.rake]
namespace :server do
  desc '[auto-pilot] Server Start'
  task start: :environment do
    # ここにサーバー起動前処理
    ` ここに サーバー起動コマンド `
  end
  desc '[auto-pilot] Server Stop'
  task stop: :environment do
    # ここにサーバー終了前処理
    ` ここに サーバー終了コマンド `
  end
end

$ rake server start
$ rake server stop
```

一連のタスクの中でサーバー起動／終了だけ外部コマンド実行にする感じです。
rakeタスク化するのであれば「サーバー起動前処理」など1つ1つをタスク化して、単独でも呼べるようにしつつ一連実行のタスクを提供するというのが正しい気がします(私はstart/stopだけでサボりますが)。

Comment: なるほど。ご丁寧にありがとうございました！今度試してみます。

Answer (score 2):

at_exitを利用すればfinalizerのようなものができると思います。

```
config/initializers/任意のファイル.rb

at_exit do
  puts '*** Stopped! ***'
end
```

[参考]
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545000/how-to-launch-a-thread-at-the-start-of-a-rails-app-and-terminate-it-at-stop
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610573/shutdown-hook-for-rails

Comment: おー。実行順序が後入れ先出しのようですが。 http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Kernel/m/at_exit.html なんてのがあったんですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます！なるほど、インタプリタのフックですか。大分ディープな感じになってきましたが笑　initializerで、finalizer的処理を登録しておいて、exit時にそれが呼ばれるってのがおもしろいですね。
config/initilizer以下に起動時の処理を配置っていうのは、ノーマルそうですね。